# How to delete newline character from a particular list item in Python

Tags: python, list, file, formatting, tuples

This code do a comparison whether (i)th and (i+1)th items' identifiers are same, it needs to replace newline with a pipe character.

```
string=""
for i in range(0,len(arrangedList)-1):
    if arrangedList[i][0]==arrangedList[i+1][0]:
        string = arrangedList[i][1][1]
        if "\n" in string:
            string.replace("\n","|")
        arrangedList[i][1][1]=string
```

However, it returns an error:

> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

I could not follow where I cast it into a tuple instead of a list.

The format of the file is as follows:

```
[0, ('Filename', './root/lib/\n')]
[0, ('Description', 'Socket\n')]
[0, ('ListenStream', 'someSocket\n')]
[0, ('SocketMode', 'someNumber\n')]
[0, ('Service', 'someService\n')]
[1, ('Filename', './root/lib/\n')]
[1, ('Description', 'Socket\n')]
[1, ('ListenStream', 'someSocket\n')]
```

Desired format will be:

```
[0, ('Filename', './root/lib/|')]
[0, ('Description', 'Socket|')]
[0, ('ListenStream', 'someSocket|')]
[0, ('SocketMode', 'someNumber|')]
[0, ('Service', 'someService\n|']
[1, ('Filename', './root/lib/|')]
[1, ('Description', 'Socket|')]
[1, ('ListenStream', 'someSocket|')]
```

Instead of some newline characters, there are '|' character now.

P.S. After some post-formatting it is going to be used in markdown table.

Comment: Could you print the content of your 'arrangedList'? From your code, it seems to be a list of lists, each one having two elements, being the second element a tuple (of two elements). If so, you trying to assign an element to a tuple (```arrangedList[i][1][1]=string```) and this is illegal in Python (tuples are immutable). You probably need a list instead of a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

It means what it says, `tuple`s are immutable, which means you cannot change the values inside them, if you want a different one, you have to create a new one.

The problem is in `arrangedList[i][1][1]=string`.

An easy fix: `arrangedList[i][1]=(arrangedList[i][1][0], string)`.

(you can assign to `arrangedList[i][1]` because it's a `list`, not a `tuple`)

Comment: Thanks at some point predefined list has changed into a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

As it was correctly mentioned tuples are immutable objects. So if your input data is in tuple form you need to convert it to, for example, lists and then make changes to the data. Try this:

```
arrangedList = [[0, ('Filename', './root/lib/\n')],
                [0, ('Description', 'Socket\n')],
                [0, ('ListenStream', 'someSocket\n')],
                [0, ('SocketMode', 'someNumber\n')],
                [0, ('Service', 'someService\n')],
                [1, ('Filename', './root/lib/\n')],
                [1, ('Description', 'Socket\n')],
                [1, ('ListenStream', 'someSocket\n')]]

# Convert the tuples to lists
for item in arrangedList:
    item[1] = list(item[1])

string=""
for i in range(0,len(arrangedList)-1):
    if arrangedList[i][0]==arrangedList[i+1][0]:
        # string = arrangedList[i][1][1]
        print('STRING: ', string)
        string = arrangedList[i][1][1]
        if "\n" in string:
            string = string.replace("\n","|")
        arrangedList[i][1][1]=string

print(arrangedList)
```

Also note, that the `replace` method returns a copy of the original string with changes. It does not change the original string.

One more thing - your output should be like this `Filename', './root/lib/|`, but not like this `'Filename', './root/lib/'|`. The pipe sign must inside of the string.

Comment: `if "\n" in string:` should go away. `string` doesn't need to be initialized to `""`. `string` is a bad name. the whole data structure should be changed from the beginning, not ad hoc in this part of the code.

Comment: @hop, I agree with you. I would give different names. My answer is about solving his problem, but not renaming his variables.